# All possible matrices (list of list) containing only elements from raw list elements python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, matrix

I need to generate this without any help of external library like numpy array.
I have size N=5 of on 5*5 matrix, and a raw list of element lets say:

```
elements = [1,2,3]
```

I want to generate all possible permutation of this grid (5*5):

for example N=5

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
]  

[[2,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
] 

[[3,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
] 

[[1,2,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
] 

[[2,2,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
] 

[[3,2,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
] 

[[1,3,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
] 

...

[[2,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
]

[[3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
 [3,3,3,3,3],
]
```

If it possible as most efficient i can generate this.
Already try `itertools.permutations` on the grid.
I change to N=5 because the number of elements is less then number that fit in the row, and it more difficult that way.

Comment: Can you check again?    
It not duplicate, because it generate all permutation of one list.   
I need to generate all possible list, and then maybe product. it harder problem.

Comment: I guess then you are not also allowed to use `itertools.permutation` ?

Comment: It not enough. You cannot do it with just  `itertools.permutation`. I check it already. It harder problem.

Comment: If you already tried...then you should post your try code to see where the bug is...may be it's simpler than you thought...

Comment: I cannot see why this is about permutations. The matrices do not at all contain the same elements in different orders. It looks like you are looking for all matrices possible containing only elements in {1,2,..N}.

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes. maybe i didn't describe in words as good as the matrix, can you rephrase my question better that people understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python this type of iterator is known as a [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
N=2
elements = [1,2,3]
B=product(elements,repeat=N)
for c in product(B,repeat=N):
    print c
```

prints

```
((1, 1), (1, 1))
((1, 1), (1, 2))
((1, 1), (1, 3))
((1, 1), (2, 1))
((1, 1), (2, 2))
((1, 1), (2, 3))
((1, 1), (3, 1))
((1, 1), (3, 2))
...
((3, 3), (3, 1))
((3, 3), (3, 2))
((3, 3), (3, 3))
```

The first product produces B: an iterator over all the choices for an individual row made out of your elements.
Then the second product produces an iterator over all the choices for a matrix made out of the rows in B.

Comment: I try and this code is give all possible matrices.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [itertools.combinations_with_replacement()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

**Example:**

```
import itertools

def get_matrices( elements, N ):
    rows = itertools.combinations_with_replacement( elements, N )
    result = itertools.combinations_with_replacement( rows, N )
    return list(result)

matrices = get_matrices( [1,2], 2 )

for matrix in matrices:
    print matrix
```

**Output:**

```
((1, 1), (1, 1))
((1, 1), (1, 2))
((1, 1), (2, 2))
((1, 2), (1, 2))
((1, 2), (2, 2))
((2, 2), (2, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:
Interpret your N x N matrix as single list of N² elements out of the set {1,2,.. M}.

Now you can interpret this List as a number to the base M (interpret M as 0)

```
e.g. (N=3, M=3)
1 2 2 
3 1 2
2 1 1
```

is the list 122312211 is the number 122012211 (base 3)

So you can simply count from `0 to (M^N²) -1` to generate all possible numbers of N² digits (base M)

```
e.g. N=3 M=3

0000000000
0000000001
0000000002
0000000010
0000000011
0000000012
0000000020
...
2222222221
2222222222
```

each of this number can be written as a 3 x 3 matrix.
e.g.

210211001 is the matrix (3==0 so)

```
2 1 3
2 1 1
3 3 1
```

This way you get all possible N x N grids with elements in {1,2.. M}

Comment: You get the digits of the base M number simply by dividing the number by M and the remainder is the last digit of the number base M. Do this until your number is 0 and you have the hole representation in base M. Shlould be easy in any language.